# How to implement JWT auth in Django with custom endpoint?

Tags: python, django, jwt

I'm learning Django ecosystem and trying to figure out how to implement JWT authentication outside of "hello world" way provided by simplejwt library (trying to build realworld.io REST API). I can't understand how can I do that: should I use simplejwt library or pyjwt and create my custom authentication logic.

For example, I want to be able to:
`POST /users` and with

```
{
  "email": "test@example.com",
  "password": "password",
  "username": "username"
}
```

and get result back

```
{
  "email": "test@example.com",
  "username": "username",
  "token": <JWT_TOKEN_HERE>
}
```

and be able to authenticate myself by sending Authentication header with `Bearer <JWT_TOKEN_HERE>`

https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt let's me create 2 endpoints with built-in functionality, but I want to customize it for my own.

Comment: Why do you want to respond with the password? By sending it twice, you make it more likely to capture it. Especially since by knowing a subsequence is the same in the request and the response, trying to decrypt the traffic might be easier.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah, you're right. I'm just tired and missed it, thank you for pay attention to this :D